# Jenkins configuration as code plugin vs Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking at options of configuring Jenkins as code. What I've found so far are those two options:

- Configuration as code plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md)
- Pipeline (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)

What I don't understand yet is how those two work with each other? Do they both do the same and should I choose either one or another? Or maybe they do different things, in such case it would be great to know if those two can actually work together.

Comment: One is for configuring your Jenkins instances, the other is for configuring pipelines within them. They operate at different levels.

Comment: `Configuration as code plugin` is used to configure your Jenkins after you setup/start a Jenkins master.  With it you no need to configure Jenkins from the web UI: Jenkins -> Manage, instead you can prepare a YAML file then execute the YAML file, this plugin will do the configuration on Jenkins master.    `Pipeline` is a kind of Jenkins Job, we use Jenkins job to execute repeat work for us, like build app deployment package from source code; run test script, etc.   Therefor,  `Configuration as code plugin` is way to config Jenkins, `Pipeline` is way to use Jenkins after you configured Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipeline to configure the build process as code.

You can use Jenkins Configuration as Code to configure the Jenkins instance as code.

You should also have a look at Job DSL Plugin to configure the jobs (everything but the build process) as code.

You may have a look at this repo to see it all work together: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/jenkins-configuration-as-code-sandbox